# How to destroy the window if the time is elapsed in Extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a  pop up window. I have to destroy this window automatically after some 5-10

seconds. Can anyone suggest an example on how to destroy a window automatically...

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a function called `MyApp.destroyWindow` that takes one parameter, an instance of `Ext.window.Window` and destroys it. Use `Ext.defer` to set a timeout.

```
Ext.defer(MyApp.destroyWindow, /* function to call */
          5000, /* timeout in milliseconds */,
          MyApp, /* scope of the called function */
          [myWindow] /* array of arguments to provide the function */
);
```

See [Ext.Function.defer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-defer) for more information on how to use it. `Ext.defer` is an alias for `Ext.Function.defer` so either invocation will work.